# Postgres select distinct row per group without repeating

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that generated matched data like this. For each parent I need to select a child but not repeat the same combination or parent or child. In the picture below, the black border shows the groups and the blue highlighted rows are the rows I want returned.

[image: Data Table]

I also have the case where there are 6 parents and only 3 children. In this case I only want 3 rows max, the child and parent ids can't repeat. I just want the first matched children to parents.

Comment: What is your expect result?

Comment: The rows highlighted in blue is the rows I wanted returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I conducting some research and found options that were close but didn't do the trick. I finally got exactly what I wanted.

```
    WITH firstmatched AS (
    SELECT parent, 
           child, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY child 
                                 ORDER BY parent DESC) AS rowkey1,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY parent 
                                 ORDER BY child DESC) AS rowkey2    
      FROM mytable)
    SELECT *
    FROM firstmatched where rowkey1 = rowkey2
```

Take the case where there are 6 parents and only children, this query without the where clause *(where rowkey1 = rowkey2)* looks like this.

[image: Matched Data]

Then with the where clause added it reduces to this.

[image: Reduced Final Data]

Hopefully this helps someone with a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Rock&Roll-method: just make all assignments and skip the errors:

---

```
\i tmp.sql

 -- The data [in non-graphical form]
CREATE TABLE tableau(
        parent integer NOT NULL
        , child integer NOT NULL
        , PRIMARY KEY (parent,child)
        ) ;

INSERT INTO tableau(parent,child) VALUES
( 450759,450768) , ( 450759,450771) , ( 450759,450773)
, ( 450763,450768) , ( 450763,450771) , ( 450763,450773)
, ( 450765,450768) , ( 450765,450771) , ( 450765,450773)
        ;

-- Receptor table for the results:
CREATE TEMP TABLE assignment(
        parent integer NOT NULL UNIQUE
        , child integer NOT NULL UNIQUE
        );

-- Just do it!
INSERT INTO assignment(parent,child)
SELECT parent,child
FROM tableau
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING --<< MAGIC!
  ;

SELECT * FROM tableau;
SELECT * FROM assignment;
```

---

Results:

---

```
CREATE SCHEMA
SET
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 9
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 3
 parent | child  
--------+--------
 450759 | 450768
 450759 | 450771
 450759 | 450773
 450763 | 450768
 450763 | 450771
 450763 | 450773
 450765 | 450768
 450765 | 450771
 450765 | 450773
(9 rows)

 parent | child  
--------+--------
 450759 | 450768
 450763 | 450771
 450765 | 450773
(3 rows)
```

---

Note: this *solution* is *greedy*; it can fail to find an optimal solution on some types of tableau data.

Comment: That is very cool, didn’t know that was an option, And I have a use for that on something else I’m working on.

Comment: It is not perfect.(but neither is your solution)

Comment: I’m not saying anything negative about your solution. I was looking for a solution that selected the data correctly. However I don’t know which executes faster. I have to conduct some testing, my query might be too slow on 1 million rows. I will let u know how the select performs, I might have to switch to your insert solution to temp table.

Comment: I am not saying anything negative. I just added a remark that both solutions could fail to reach an optimal  solution on some types of input. (your example data is rather good-shaped)

Comment: Ok, sorry, misread that, your right. The data in prod will be millions of rows so I’m not sure how fast that sql statement will be. Your insert solution I know will be fast into a temp table. I’m curious to find out.